# Phantom Stylesheet

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, xslt

I have a situation where IE seems to be loading a non-existent xls file.

I am using MZTools to document some VBA code in Excel.  MZTools has an xsl file called sample.xsl, in C:\Program Files\MZTools3VBA.  [image]

I saved the original xsl and made a bunch of modifications to get the layout the way I like it and it works fine.
A couple of weeks later, I decided to tweak it a bit more but, when I opened the xsl file it was the original content (as-shipped sample.xsl).  I thought: OK, I guess I made a mistake when managing the versions of the file.

The strange this is, the changes I made persist.  When I created a new xml report, IE is still loading the modified styles.
MZTools is set up to use the default xsl file to style the report and that's confirmed by the xml it generates.
MZTools settings...
[image]
MZTools-generated xml...
[image]

The href points to this file...
[image]
...which has the original style selectors and a slightly different annotation at the top

but this is what's loaded by IE...
[image]

It has the styles and annotation of the modified file
[image]

I changed the name of the xsl file to see what would happen and it made no difference, its as if the file is there but as a phantom copy that IE can find.
[image]

IE still pulls the new styling from somewhere
[image]

My question is: Where is my `<!--expletive deleted--!>` style file?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.

Probably because of structure created by Aptana Studio when promoting a system folder (requiring Administrator rights) to a project, that was not removed when the project was deleted in Aptana, files open in Aptana's workspace (even after Aptana is closed) will dissapear from Windows Explorer Folders if they are subsequently re-named.  But they will still be visible to IE!

So if you have a file open in Aptana called file1 and you close Aptana and re-name the file to file2 in Windows Explorer, then file1 will remain as a separate, but invisible file in WE. IE however, will continue to resolve references to the file1.  And subsequently created, distinct references to file2 for that matter!

1. Open Aptana Studio 3 and open sample1.xls from the file system
   -sample1.xsl is in a folder in C:\Program Files\MZTools3VBA
2. Edit the xsl
3. Open an xml file referencing sample1.xsl in IE and confirm the edits.  Leave the page open in IE
4. Save, then close AS
5. Navigate to C:\Program Files\MZTools3VBA in Windows Explorer and
   change the name of sample1.xsl to sample12.xsl.  Now, acording to WE, there is no file in C:\Program Files\MZTools3VBA called sample1.xsl.
6. Refresh the page in IE -it refreshes fine, IE found C:\Program
   Files\MZTools3VBA\sample1.xsl Check again: No, still can't see
   sample1.xsl in C:\Program Files\MZTools3VBA with WE
7. Open Aptana Studio -sample1.xsl is open and hovering on it's tab
   shows it is located in C:\Program Files\MZTools3VBA.
8. Navigate to that folder in AS and yep, there it is.  Check again in
   WE... nope, still not there.
9. Make some edits in AS and save and refresh the page in IE to confirm the edits.  Yep, IE shows the edits: according to IE, the file still exists.

You can see in this screen shot, that sample1.xls (which is open in Aptana) and another file called sample.xsl.bak, are invisible in Windows Explorer...
[image]

Thats a day I'll never get back...